# Do we need to know/find/analyze every case {Best, Average and Worst...all} scenarios of an algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

In the books about data-structures and algorithms, we often see that they do not analyze every case scenarios of all algorithms.

Some algorithms are discussed along with average case, some are with average and worst case and others are all of best, average and worst.

Why they tend to do that?

Why don't we need to know all cases for all algorithms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best case is generally useless unless you control the inputs. (i.e. best case is usually an anomalous case). Unless it's easy to compute, it's not worth wasting your time.

Average case: it's what can you expect in general.  Assuming you work with a large range of inputs, this is usually the most useful thing to consider.

Worst case: a decent tie breaker for two algorithms with the same average case, if you deal with arbitrary inputs (especially if they're untrusted - i.e. you're accepting inputs from people on the web).  Also something to consider in design in general - this will come up occasionally.  In general, if you have two algorithms that are O(n) average case, but one is O(n lg n) worst case, and one is O(n^2) - it may influence your decision on which to go with.  Or it may influence your algorithm design.

Example: quick sort v. merge sort. Both are O(n lg n)  Quicksort's worst case is O(n^2), merge sort is (IIRC) still O(n lg n) - but in general, Quicksort tends to be faster if data fits in memory.  Even though it has a costlier worst case, since we KNOW it has a costlier worst case, we can try to mitigate it (median-of-three instead of just a random partition, etc.) and take advantage of the fact that it usually is faster than mergesort.

Comment: +1 for this good analysis. It doesn't answer the question though. I think it's because often it is trivial. For example many sorting algorithms are O(n log n) in the worst case but also on the average case. Also, lookup hashing worst case O(n) sounds really bad but that rarely happens and what's more important is that it's O(1) on the average case.

Comment: @James Just of curosity. the range of worst case- best case should me min as possible or max?

Comment: @Shuddh -  In an ideal world, you want all of the above (worst, best, average) to be as small as possible.   In the real world, you'll likely be choosing one algorithm over another based on what tradeoffs are appropriate to the problem at hand.  Best case rarely matters.  Average case is important if your focus is throughput.  Worst case becomes more important if you care about minimizing user-perceived latency, for instance.

Answer (score 3):

Worst case analysis is usually the most useful way to spend a moderate amount of effort analysing an algorithm. Average case is more complicated, because the average case usually depends on how likely different inputs are, so you have to say what the average case is in terms of what the probability is in terms of different inputs. Best case is not very useful because a hope that my program might complete in 1 second does not allow me to plan some activity that will take too long if my program actually takes 3 hours. Knowing that, no matter what, it will complete in five minutes, is much more useful.

Best case also has a problem with programs that store a small number of pre-prepared inputs and outputs, then check the input they get against the pre-prepared inputs. If they get a match, then they respond with the pre-prepared output without doing anything else and so get great - but meaningless - best case behaviour.

There are some cases where worst case analysis is not what you want. Somebody designing an encryption algorithm might want a guarantee that nobody can break it in less than 10 years (unfortunately, typically such guarantees don't exist).